# How to use ServiceStack's Request Logger without using roles?

Tags: servicestack

In my application I am using a custom request filter in order to authenticate the users using basic authentication. And I want to use  the Request Logger that I have registered as shown below:

```
Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature { EnableSessionTracking = false });
```

When I execute request on /requestlogs I get following error:

```
{
  "Results": [],
  "ResponseStatus": {
    "ErrorCode": "Invalid Role",
    "Message": "Invalid Role",
    "StackTrace": "[RequestLogs: 10.08.2014 19:29:03]:\n[REQUEST: {Skip:0}]\nServiceStack.Common.Web.HttpError: Invalid Role\r\n   at ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.RequiredRoleAttribute.AssertRequiredRoles(IRequestContext requestContext, String[] requiredRoles)\r\n   at ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Admin.RequestLogsService.Any(RequestLogs request)\r\n   at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequestContext requestContext, Object instance, TRequest request)",
    "Errors": []
  }
}
```

How can I force the Request Logger to use my basic authentication Request Filter and to ignore roles that I am not using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the requirement for the roles:

```cs
Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature { 
    EnableSessionTracking = false,
    RequiredRoles = null
});
```

You can find the various settings of the [`RequestLogFeature` here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/RequestLogsFeature.cs)

To prevent access to the Request logs without using your authentication you can apply your basic authentication filter attribute to it using:

```cs
typeof(RequestLogsService).AddAttributes(MyAuthenticateAttribute);
```

Where `MyAuthenticateAttribute` is the name of your basic auth filter attribute.